# How js `this` actually works?

Tags: javascript

So I know that in JS function's `this` depends on where it called not where defined but why in the next code I get `window` object instead of `obj` ?

```js
function foo(){
  bar();
}

function bar(){
  console.dir(this);
}

var obj={name:'foobar',f:foo};

obj.f();
```

Comment: `function foo(){
  bar.call(this);
}

function bar(){
  console.dir(this);
}

var obj={name:'foobar',f:foo.bind(this)};

obj.f();` This code will give you the required result. And please read the linked question for more details

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanna know why it doesn't work in my example